# How to override a setting to a new value in a task or configuration?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have default value for some setting. When I call `distrib:package` (`distrib` is new configuration) or `distrib` task (in default configuration), I want to override this setting.
This setting is set for some subprojects with a project that depends on them.

more specific:

I use xsbt-web-plugin for packaging server in war file. in I have a setting like

```
webappPostProcess := { webappDir => (webstart in guiClient).value;
  IO.copy((webstartOutput in client).value, webappDir / "client") 
}
```

for building WebStart client and copying it to war file directory. in `guiClient` project I have a setting `useTsa := false` (from custom plugin). I want to set this setting to true when I publish server.

Currently I have `lazy val Distrib = config("distrib").extend(Compile)` and `webstartSettings ++ Seq(useTsa := false) ++ inConfig(Distrib)(webstartSettings ++ Seq(useTsa := true))`.  it works with `package` (`useTsa` is false) and `distrib:package` (`useTsa` is true). but  in `distrib:publish` setting `useTsa` is false.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to re-set a setting you have to `reload` the project. It is not possible from within a task, and you need a command that is (pretty much) a function accepting a `State` and returning a new `State`. That's where you can set the setting to a new value.

Read on [Commands](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Commands.html).

If you however want to have different values of a setting per configuration, it's as simple as this (in `build.sbt`):

```
lazy val abc = settingKey[String]("A sample ABC setting")
abc in Compile := "abc in Compile"
abc in Test := "abc in Test"
```

And then in the shell:

```
> show compile:abc
[info] abc in Compile
> show test:abc
[info] abc in Test
```

Read [Keys](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Basic-Def.html#Keys).

Comment: This is not what I want to do. I want to have some kind of profile with different values of some settings. so, when I develop I use one set of settings, when I need to release I use another. I suppose it is possible with configurations, but I don't understand how they work.

Comment: I've provided more info in the question

Comment: I still don't understand *"I want to override this setting. This setting is set for some subprojects with a project that depends on them."* from your question. And the update didn't really help much. Sorry.